# Autohotkey Key for hiding current window

Tags: autohotkey

I try to close a window with the below configuration when pressing Ctrl and h.
Unfortunately it does not work.
E.g. in Chrome it opens the little window as if you press alt+space, when I focus the address bar in Chrome it works.

What do I do wrong?

```
;Hide a window
^h:: Send !{Space}n
Return
```

Comment: What is Alt+Space supposed to be? And what sort of window hiding are you looking to do? Maybe `WinHide`? Maybe `WinMinimize`? The commands are straight built into AHK.

Comment: Its Alt+Space+n, it hides current window in Windows OS. I was not successfull with those build in commands, can you show an example with my code using WinHide?

Comment: Show what you tried and I can say what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a solution which fixes my issue:

I now use [Kinto](https://kinto.sh/), which itself uses AutoHotkey, and it has the key action I want right from the start using the Mac OS Layout from the Kinto Installation Options.

Kinto itself uses AutoHotkey, you can find the [AutoHotkey-file](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto/blob/master/windows/kinto.ahk) on Github.